# Is there any way to differentiate between a string and an ident in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

```
macro_rules! mtc {
    ( $ident:ident ) => ("ident");
    ( $string:expr ) => ("string");
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", mtc!("hi"));
    println!("{}", mtc!(a));
}
```

This doesn't work. It fails with:

```
<anon>:7:25: 7:29 error: expected ident, found "hi"
<anon>:7     println!("{}", mtc!("hi"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `macro_rules!` machinery cannot back out of a capture.  Once it starts *trying* to match a capture, it either succeeds or the *entire macro invocation fails*.

In order to do this, you have to provide some kind of literal match *prior* to the capture that `macro_rules!` can use to distinguish between the rules.  For example:

```rust
macro_rules! mtc {
    ( ident $ident:ident ) => ("ident");
    ( expr $string:expr ) => ("string");
}
```

Also, to answer the implicit question: no, there is no way to *specifically* match a string literal, or indeed any *other* kind of literal.